# Script for updating DB

Tags: perl, dbi

I have the following piece of perl script for updating Oracle Database. It's working perfectly fine; but, I want to know how to simplify this script:

```
use DBI;
my $dbh;
my $bad_form = "text.txt";

open (OUT, $bad_form) or die "Could not open $bad_form";
while (<OUT>){
    chomp $_;
    my ($item_id, $description, $form_id_1, $form_id_3) = split(/\|/, $_);

    my $new_form_id_1 = form_1($form_id_1);
    my $new_form_id_3 = form_3($form_id_3);

    if ( $new_form_id_1 ne 'null' ){
            my $sql = "update item_table set form_id_1 = '$new_form_id_1' where item_id = '$item_id'";
            my $item = $dbh->prepare($sql) or (log_error("Couldn't prepare statement: " . $dbh->errstr) and return 2);
            $item->execute() or (log_error("Couldn't execute statement: " . $item->errstr) and return 2);
    }else{
            $form_id_1 = "correct value";
            $new_form_id_1 = "no updated";
    }

    if ( $new_form_id_3 ne 'null' ){
            my $sql = "update item_table set form_id_3 = '$new_form_id_3' where item_id = '$item_id'";
            my $item = $dbh->prepare($sql) or (log_error("Couldn't prepare statement: " . $dbh->errstr) and return 2);
            $item->execute() or (log_error("Couldn't execute statement: " . $item->errstr) and return 2);

    }else{
            $form_id_3 = "correct value";
            $new_form_id_3 = "no updated";
    }
}
```

Where function form_1() and form_3() are used to generated new value for form_id_1,3.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: This question would be more appropriate over at [codereview.se]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Code Review SE

Answer (score 1):

use strict;

Move your two `prepare()`s out of the `while` loop, using `?` as placeholder. Then call only `execute($new_form_id_x, $item_id)` for the appropriate prepared statement handle inside the loop.